# Django 2.2.1: Modifying the relationship of a OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models

In Django 2.2.1, I have two models related via a OneToOneField:

```py
class Woman(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Man(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    wife = models.OneToOneField(
        Woman,
        related_name = 'husband',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

(Heteronormative for simplicity.) But as we all know, marriages fail. However, I am having a terrible time modifying the relationship:

```py
>>> john = Man.objects.create(name='John')
>>> alice = Woman.objects.create(name='Alice')
>>> susan = Woman.objects.create(name='Susan')
>>> john.wife = alice
>>> alice.husband
<Man: John>
# After the divorce...
>>> john.wife = susan
>>> susan.husband
<Man: John>
>>> alice.husband
<Man: John>
>>> susan.save()

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: appname_woman.husband_id
```

Okay, this makes sense: Two Woman objects can't have the same husband (at least under current U.S. law). No problem; what if I delete the original wife from the relationship?

```py
>>> alice.husband = None
>>> alice.save()
>>> alice.husband # None
>>> susan.husband
<Man: John>
# Oh good, no errors. And John is now married to Susan... right? Wrong.
>>> john.save()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 415, in __get__
    self.related.get_accessor_name()
appname.models.Man.wife.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Man has no wife.
```

It appears that the only way to make this work is to make sure to divorce John before he remarries:

```py
# Starting with a clean database
>>> john = Man.objects.create(name='John')
>>> alice = Woman.objects.create(name='Alice')
>>> susan = Woman.objects.create(name='Susan')
>>> john.wife = alice
>>> alice.husband
<Man: John>
# The marriage was brief...
>>> john.wife = None
>>> john.save()
>>> john.wife = susan
>>> john.save()
>>> susan.save()
>>> alice.save()
# Everybody's happy, we hope.
```

What a mess! Now, here's my question: How can I write code to ensure that any time a Man objects gets assigned to a new Man.wife, the previous Man.wife is removed and validation passes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making this much harder than it needs to be. You just didn't save `john` after modifying him.

This would work:

```
>>> john = Man.objects.create(name='John')
>>> alice = Woman.objects.create(name='Alice')
>>> susan = Woman.objects.create(name='Susan')
>>> john.wife = alice
>>> john.save()
>>> john.wife = susan
>>> john.save()
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. I've just copied your own code, but added the two `save` calls.

Answer (score 0):

try this function,

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist


def marriage(man_name, women_instance):
    try:
        women_instance.husband = None
        women_instance.save()
        return Man.objects.create(name=man_name, wife=women_instance)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return Man.objects.create(name=man_name, wife=women_instance)
```

---

#### Usage

```
women_instance = Woman.objects.get(name="bar")
man_name = "Foo"
man_instance = marriage(man_name, women_instance)
```

Comment: just let it standalone. But, When you plan to create a `Man` instance (a marriage), use this function.